# Toggle Inline Chevron Down when activating bootstrap collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not sure if the title made sense, but from PHP I'm echoing this HTML in a loop:

```
<a href='#' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#myid'>
  <span class='fa fa-caret-down'></span>
</a>
<div id='myid' class='collapse'>Some Content</div>
```

I want the `fa-caret-down` to change to `fa-caret-up` when clicked, and vice versa.  I want to the code to be inline, so I can output it in just this one instance.  How can I do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass. Also, don't put code inline. Add a class to the element you want this logic to work on, then hook the click event handler to that class.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, this is for error reporting so Its a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the `onClick` inline event to your anchor and attach a function that toggles between classes to it like :

```js
function toggleClass(self) {
  $('span', self).toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-up');
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='#' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#myid' onClick="toggleClass(this)">
  <span class='fa fa-caret-down'></span>
</a>
<div id='myid' class='collapse'>Some Content</div>
```

**Suggestion**

It will be better to use a common class in all of your anchors, and attach the click event to this common class, like :

```
<a href='#' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#myid' class="icon_toggle">
    <span class='fa fa-caret-down'></span>
</a>
<div id='myid' class='collapse'>Some Content</div>
```

In your js code you should attach the click event that toggle between the both classes using the jQuery method [`toogleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) like :

```
$('body').on('click', '.icon_toggle', function(){
     $('span', this).toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-up');
});
```

Comment: I understand that its *better*, But thats not what I asked for.

Comment: Updated with solution you're searching for

Comment: Thanks! Would there be a way to get it all into the onclick?

Comment: Yes, it will be work for them all, I suggest to change the `id`, else you'll end with invalid HTML code that contains duplicate `id`'s

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

If someone's interested in handling this with Vanilla JS without using external libraries.

```js
var carets = document.querySelectorAll('.up-down');

carets.forEach(function(caret){
  caret.addEventListener("click", function(){
     this.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].classList.toggle('fa-caret-down');
     this.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].classList.toggle('fa-caret-up');
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href='#' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#myid' class="up-down">
  <span class='fa fa-caret-down'></span>
</a>

<div id='myid' class='collapse'>Some Content</div>
```